# GRUB starts every other time

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub

My Ubuntu install only gets to the grub menu every other time (sometimes not even). Other times it shows a blank screen with a strange line of artifacts along the top.

[image: screen artifacts]

I'm not sure how to approach this.

Results of `/etc/lsb-release` :

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=utopic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.10"
```

Results of `lshw` :

```
steamerduck
    description: Desktop Computer
    product: M51AC (All)
    vendor: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
    version: System Version
    serial: DAPDCG001YN1
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 vsyscall32
    configuration: administrator_password=disabled boot=normal chassis=desktop family=Desktop frontpanel_password=disabled keyboard_password=disabled power-on_password=disabled sku=All uuid=F785E5B8-6B32-FB8F-3F0C-D850E6C1FFF2
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: M51AC
       vendor: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
       physical id: 0
       version: Rev X.0x
       serial: 130916275700101
       slot: To be filled by O.E.M.
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: 0901
          date: 07/25/2013
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 15MiB
          capabilities: pci apm upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-memory:0 UNCLAIMED
          physical id: 1
        *-bank UNCLAIMED
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
             product: MI64C1D1629Z1
             vendor: Fujitsu
             physical id: 0
             serial: 00002545
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
             size: 8GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     *-memory:1
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 41
          slot: System board or motherboard
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM [empty]
             product: [Empty]
             vendor: [Empty]
             physical id: 0
             serial: [Empty]
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
             product: MI64C1D1629Z1
             vendor: Fujitsu
             physical id: 1
             serial: 00010348
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
             size: 8GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
        *-bank:2
             description: DIMM [empty]
             product: [Empty]
             vendor: [Empty]
             physical id: 2
             serial: [Empty]
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
     *-cache:0
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 48
          slot: CPU Internal L1
          size: 256KiB
          capacity: 256KiB
          capabilities: internal write-back
     *-cache:1
          description: L2 cache
          physical id: 49
          slot: CPU Internal L2
          size: 1MiB
          capacity: 1MiB
          capabilities: internal write-back unified
     *-cache:2
          description: L3 cache
          physical id: 4a
          slot: CPU Internal L3
          size: 8MiB
          capacity: 8MiB
          capabilities: internal write-back unified
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 4e
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
          slot: SOCKET 1150
          size: 2893MHz
          capacity: 3900MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=8
     *-memory:2 UNCLAIMED
          physical id: 2
     *-memory:3 UNCLAIMED
          physical id: 3
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 06
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=hsw_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 06
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:40 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:f6000000-f70fffff ioport:e8000000(size=167772160)
           *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: GF119 [GeForce GT 620 OEM]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: a1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
                resources: irq:45 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e8000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
           *-multimedia
                description: Audio device
                product: GF119 HDMI Audio Controller
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0.1
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
                version: a1
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
                resources: irq:17 memory:f7080000-f7083fff
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 05
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:41 memory:f7200000-f720ffff
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:44 memory:f721b000-f721b00f
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:20 memory:f7218000-f72183ff
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 05
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:46 memory:f7210000-f7213fff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: d5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
             version: d5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:18 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:f7100000-f71fffff ioport:f2100000(size=1048576)
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: p2p1
                version: 0c
                serial: d8:50:e6:c1:ff:f2
                size: 1Gbit/s
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 ip=10.200.8.1 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
                resources: irq:43 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7100000-f7100fff memory:f2100000-f2103fff
        *-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:23 memory:f7217000-f72173ff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: H87 Express LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:42 ioport:f070(size=8) ioport:f060(size=4) ioport:f050(size=8) ioport:f040(size=4) ioport:f020(size=32) memory:f7216000-f72167ff
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 05
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f7215000-f72150ff ioport:f000(size=32)
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: 4
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: ST1000DM003-1CH1
             vendor: Seagate
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: CC44
             serial: S1DFDD7H
             size: 931GiB (1TB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=0a91f613-f745-44f9-8fe0-41b293aed014 sectorsize=4096
           *-volume:0
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: mkfs.fat
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                logical name: /boot/efi
                version: FAT32
                serial: d7a3-dd22
                size: 510MiB
                capacity: 511MiB
                capabilities: fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat mount.fstype=vfat mount.options=rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro state=mounted
           *-volume:1
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                logical name: /
                version: 1.0
                serial: 6c2d46cb-cd6c-448e-878a-917593a1f9d9
                size: 915GiB
                capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2015-04-22 11:25:46 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2015-05-06 10:18:47 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered mounted=2015-05-06 10:18:47 state=mounted
           *-volume:2
                description: Linux swap volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sda3
                version: 1
                serial: d382d094-e701-4d7f-9da1-beb6d0a35734
                size: 15GiB
                capacity: 15GiB
                capabilities: nofs swap initialized
                configuration: filesystem=swap pagesize=4095
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: 5
          logical name: scsi5
          capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             product: DVD A  DH24ACSH
             vendor: ATAPI
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@5:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/cdrw
             logical name: /dev/dvd
             logical name: /dev/dvdrw
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             version: LAA4
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=ready
           *-medium
                physical id: 0
                logical name: /dev/cdrom
                capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
                configuration: signature=1c62b002
              *-volume UNCLAIMED
                   description: Windows FAT volume
                   vendor: mkfs.fat
                   physical id: 2
                   version: FAT12
                   serial: d5c9-8bb9
                   size: 15EiB
                   capabilities: primary fat initialized
                   configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat label=Firmware
     *-scsi:2
          physical id: 6
          bus info: usb@1:1.2
          logical name: scsi6
          capabilities: emulated scsi-host
          configuration: driver=usb-storage
        *-disk:0
             description: SCSI Disk
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@6:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdb
             configuration: sectorsize=512
        *-disk:1
             description: SCSI Disk
             physical id: 0.0.1
             bus info: scsi@6:0.0.1
             logical name: /dev/sdc
             configuration: sectorsize=512
        *-disk:2
             description: SCSI Disk
             physical id: 0.0.2
             bus info: scsi@6:0.0.2
             logical name: /dev/sdd
             configuration: sectorsize=512
        *-disk:3
             description: SCSI Disk
             physical id: 0.0.3
             bus info: scsi@6:0.0.3
             logical name: /dev/sde
             configuration: sectorsize=512
  *-power UNCLAIMED
       description: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       product: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       vendor: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       physical id: 1
       version: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       capacity: 32768mWh
```

Results of `/etc/default/grub` :

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Results of `smartctl` :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that grub would automatically boot using the default configuration. This default config would mess something up with the display settings.

When this happened, I would hold the power button to cycle the machine. The next time it booted up, it noticed that there wasn't a clean shutdown so I got presented with the grub menu.

Selecting the entry in the menu would cause it boot successfully. The solution is to **hold shift during the boot** to force the menu to appear.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tested the hard drive to see if there are errors? Check your SMART logs and run something like Spinrite or Drive Fitness Test. To me that sounds like read errors (bad sectors) causing the error correction rate to be too high where the hard drive gives up.

Comment: I ran the "extended self-test" using smartctl but it "Completed without error". I posted the attributes table.